# Excel: Ensembl continue, how to save to CSV file after change R

Tags: r, biomart

Related to
[Unable to use biomaRt package to get Gene Symbols from Entrez IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265798/unable-to-use-biomart-package-to-get-gene-symbols-from-entrez-ids/60304924?noredirect=1#comment106673336_60304924)

The code is working like a charm, but I would like to save it to my **current** CSV file and not only "viewing" it (adding an additional column will do the work as well, I got over 65k ids)

```
library(biomaRt)
marts <- listMarts()
ensembl <- useMart("ensembl")
datasets <- listDatasets(ensembl)
ensembl=useDataset("hsapiens_gene_ensembl",mart=ensembl)
attributes <- listAttributes(ensembl)
my_ids <- read.csv("LUADhtseq.csv")
ensembl = useEnsembl(biomart="ensembl", dataset="hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
results_end_1 <- getBM(attributes = c("ensembl_gene_id","external_gene_name"), values = my_ids, mart = ensembl )
View(results_end_1)
```

Comment: So you want to add another column to my_ids data.frame?

Comment: `write.csv(results_end_1, "filename.csv")`

Comment: Pardon me, I wasn't clear enough. I am trying to change the Ensembl ID inside the file I am already using "LUADhtseq" or create a column beside the Ensembl_ID column, both are fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting back all the entries in ensembl, and you need to merge:

```
my_ids = data.frame(ids=c("ENSG00000130203","ENSG00000136717","ENSG00000186868"))

df = merge(my_ids,results_end_1,by.x="ids",by.y="ensembl_gene_id")
df
              ids external_gene_name
1 ENSG00000130203               APOE
2 ENSG00000136717               BIN1
3 ENSG00000186868               MAPT
```

Or you need to set the "filters" option to get the entries in my_ids, :

```
out <- getBM(attributes = c("ensembl_gene_id","external_gene_name"), 
values = my_ids, mart = ensembl,filters="ensembl_gene_id")

  ensembl_gene_id external_gene_name
1 ENSG00000130203               APOE
2 ENSG00000136717               BIN1
3 ENSG00000186868               MAPT
```

And you can write:

```
write.csv(out,"out.csv",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
```